# Getting URLs of all the photos in a Flickr album using Flickr API

Tags: php, android, rest, flickr

I use this to get all the albums list using Flickr API -

```
flickr.photosets.getList
```

I need to get static URLs of all the photos in a particular album. Can anyone suggest how ?

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/, specifically https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html

Comment: Thanks. Its done. flickr.photosets.getPhotos does that. Its giving IDs of all photos. I can get static URLs from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flicker.photosets.getPhotos` does what you want. From this you could get all the info you could want about the image through by calling `flicker.photos.getInfo` and pass in the image id.

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html

Comment: Im getting all the info. Can you tell how can I go about getting cover photo of an album ?

Comment: In a photoset the primary set in the parent opbject will be the cover photo:
`<photoset id="4" primary="2483" page="1" perpage="500" pages="1" total="2">
  <photo id="2484" secret="123456" server="1" title="my photo" isprimary="0" />
  <photo id="2483" secret="123456" server="1" title="flickr rocks" isprimary="1" />
</photoset>`
So if you have the id from photoset you can match it up to a photo

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get url of originals images (or another size) use `flicker.photosets.getPhotos` API calling it with parameter `extras=url_o` , with this parameter API will return for each photo in album its url of original image.

`https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=Your_API_Ket&photoset_id=Your_Photoset_Id&user_id=User_Id_Of_Photoset&extras=url_o&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`

More Info https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html

Comment: Thank you for extras=url_o, very helpful